# Output process - save data in file

Tags: python, file, pointers, save, output

Briefly, I'm testing this code in python:

My idea is to save `solut = one + two` in a file after inputting the values by keyboard, but now I have a problem. NO message error and nothing is written in file.

python 2.7

I have changed and saved the code and failed and I don't have a backup. I can´t remember how I need  to handle an integer and convert in a pointer.

```
filex = open('test.txt', 'a+')
one = input("first number : \n -> ")
two = input("second number: \n -> ")
solut = one + two
    for line in filex:
    line = filex.writelines(solut)
filex.close()
```

Comment: Please consider rephrasing the question. Now it is completely unclear what problem you're trying to solve, what you've tried so far and where you stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
one = int(input("first number : \n -> "))
two = int(input("second number: \n -> "))
solut = one + two
with open('test.txt', 'a+') as filex:
    filex.writelines([str(solut)])
```

You can use the int() function to convert the string that is input to an integer.  Writelines() accepts a list of strings.

Comment: woooow! yes, its works.  I'm sure that your way is much easier than the one I had implemented and i never think something like that.
Really, Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!  Oftentimes, if you find yourself using many lines of code in python, take a step back and see if there's a better way to attack the problem.  Oftentimes it can be done in a much simpler manner.  Also, please do accept the answer if all works as expected.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the variable to a file, use the following code:

```
    with open('test.txt', 'a+') as inputfile:
        one = int(raw_input())
        two = int(raw_input())
        sum = one + two
        inputfile.write(str(sum))
```

Comment: and its other form.  Thanks you, too. I need check 'as' I have forgotten how it works.